# Help solving t_echo php error while using echo do_shortcode

Tags: php

I am using the Orbit Slider plugin successfully on my site.  The plugin supports its own categories.  I would like to embed the slider within my page.php template but allow each page to have it's own slider based on the category.

Inside my page.php I have this:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[orbit-slider category="page"]'); ?>`

the category "page" is just the name of a category I created.  It will display only slides that come from category.

Instead of hard-coding the category, I wanted to use custom fields so that on each individual page my client can specify a category to be shown.  I have tried something like this but it's causing an internal server error:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[orbit-slider category="' echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "slide-category", true);'"]'); ?>`

> [09-Feb-2012 20:05:08] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /public_html/wp-content/themes/techmd960/page.php on line 21

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?  I figure it has to do with the quotes (double and single) but can't figure it out.

Essentially I just want to output the custom field "slide-category" as the value for category="" in the shortcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got an `echo` inside an `echo`.

Rewrite you code like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[orbit-slider category="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "slide-category", true) . '"]'); ?>
```

This will concatenate things instead. and give you `'[orbit-slider category="5"]'` inside the `do_shortcode()` function.